# Plotting Curved Lines in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I'd like to plot curved lines of a specific arch like shape, below is how far I've gotten using specific values (these values need to be used) but it plots straight lines.

I'm also having trouble formatting the y axis the way I want. It's a log scale and I'd like it to go up to 1 (like in the ideal plot above). Some help would be great, thanks! =)

Comment: Let me guess - the shape you want for the curved lines is based on linearly interpolating the underlying values, and then having those interpolated values plotted on a log axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your line is not stretching on a log scale plot is because there are no points between the points that are on the top and on the bottom. `log plot` does not curve the lines, only place the points on a different scale, the line between them are still straight.

To change this, we add more points between dots. and the result will become curved.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

# Data for plotting
t = [0.0, 62.5, 125.0, 187.5, 250, 312.5, 375, 437.5, 500]
s = [0.1, 0.005, 0.1, 0.005, 0.1, 0.005, 0.1, 0.005, 0.1]

def extendlist(l):
    master = []
    for i in range(len(l)-1):
        x = np.linspace(l[i], l[i+1], 50)
        master.extend(x)
    return master

t = extendlist(t)
s = extendlist(s)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.semilogy(t, s)

ax.set(xlabel='x axis', ylabel='y axis', title='Stuff')
plt.xlim((0,500))
plt.ylim((0.001, 1))

plt.show()
```

This will generate what you graphed on paper.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

t = [0.0, 62.5, 125.0, 187.5, 250, 312.5, 375, 437.5, 500]
s = [0.1, 0.005, 0.1, 0.005, 0.1, 0.005, 0.1, 0.005, 0.1]
tnew = np.linspace(0, 500, num=1001, endpoint=True)
f = interp1d(t, s)
plt.semilogy(tnew, f(tnew))
plt.ylim((0.001, 1))
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Did you forget something in your code? What is `f` and where is `interp` used?